# JQuery autocomplete combobox selecting from one repopulates another

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an ASP.NET web app that is using JQuery autocomplete to build a nice dynamic combobox.  One of the boxes on the page fires a change event that reloads another box.  Basically like a UserGroup / Members scenario.  My change event fires and repopulates the underlying select box, I then do a remove on the input and button that build the combobox - which all work great up to this point.  My last line is to call the combobox method on the newly repopulated select which doesn't seem to fire ?  The standard select shows with the new data but no JQuery Goodness.   Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

On Change Event:

```
function GetAnalysts() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GetAnalystByGroup.ashx",
                data: 'group=' + $("#<%=supportGroup.ClientID%>" + " option:selected").text(),
                success: function (response) {
                    var analysts = eval(response);
                    $("#<%=assignedAnalyst.ClientID%>").children().remove();
                    $("#<%=assignedAnalyst.ClientID%>").append($('<option></option>').val('').html(firstoption));
                    for (var i = 0; i < analysts.length; i++) {
                        var text = analysts[i]['label'];
                        var val = analysts[i]['upn'];
                        $("#<%=assignedAnalyst.ClientID%>").append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
                    }
                    //remove the JQ Combo then rebuild it
                    $("#<%=assignedAnalyst.ClientID%>JQ").remove();
                    $("#<%=assignedAnalyst.ClientID%>JQBut").remove();
                    $("#<%=assignedAnalyst.ClientID%>").show();
                    $("#<%=assignedAnalyst.ClientID%>").combobox();
                },
                error: function () {
                 }
            });
        }
```

Comment: `var analyst = '<%= assignedAnalyst.ClientID %>';` will make your code much more legible.

Comment: What are the JQ and JQBut elements you are attempting to remove?

Comment: Those are the input and button elements that are used to build the pretty combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around the problem by coding the remove/show lines into a javascript pageload event and moving the AJAX call inside an update panel.